# Material UI Display property not hiding content

Tags: material-ui

Material UI explains Display in their [docs](https://material-ui.com/system/display/) as a way to Quickly and responsively toggle the display value of components!
I have an icon that i want it to be hidden on xs. I am trying
`display={{ xs: 'none', sm: 'block' }}` its not working.
I am trying `display='none'` just to see if it hides, also not working. If i set a `className={classes.icon}` and then i create an icon class in useStyles

```
 icon: {
    display: none,
  },
```

the icon is hidden.
The behaviour is making me go crazy but am sure i am missing a concept on how these things rended or something is overriding the behaviour.
Also i dont know how to use `display={{ xs: 'none', sm: 'block' }}` inside the useStyle as double brackets are not allowed there

Here is full code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
 

  icon: {
    paddingRight: 10,
    color: 'white',
    display: 'none', //setting this hides the icon
  },
```

}

```
<Grid item container xs={12}>
  <AccountBalanceIcon fontSize='large' className={classes.icon} display={{ xs: 'none', sm: 'block' }}/>           
</Grid>
```

Comment: May you provide a little bit more code?

Comment: added the code to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'display' property belongs to 'Box' component, not the Icon component.. I.e. the Icon must be wrapped in the Box component. The following sample works:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
  Box
} from '@material-ui/core';
import AdbIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Adb';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  icon: {
    color: 'red',
    //display: 'none',
  }
}));

export default function ButtonSizes() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Box
      display="block"
      //display="none" 
    >
      <AdbIcon
        fontSize="large"
        className={classes.icon}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Great thank you. This works great. Any idea how to put `display={{ xs: 'none', sm: 'block' }}` in the useStyle hook instead of the Component tag? Thank you again

Comment: xs, sm, xl.. are property objects, they are not css.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the `AdbIcon` when the screen's width becomes `xs` by using `[theme.breakpoints.only("xs")]` in the `useStyles` hook :-

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
  Box
} from '@material-ui/core';
import AdbIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Adb';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  icon: {
    color: 'red',
    [theme.breakpoints.only("xs")]: {
      display: "none",
    },
  }
}));

export default function ButtonSizes() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
   
      <AdbIcon
        fontSize="large"
        className={classes.icon}
      />
    
  );
}
```

Read about all the breakpoint queries that are given by `material-ui` [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#css-media-queries)

Comment: thanks Abdullah. I am better experienced now and right i am using this approach. Thank you hope this helps someone.